# Splitting an Avro file?

Tags: avro, command-line-tool, avro-tools

The [Avro-Tools](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/gettingstartedjava.html) package provides an easy way to concatenate multiple avro files together, however there doesn't seem to be an easy way to split files.

Does anyone know of a simple command-line tool that allows one to split an Avro file?

Comment: or at least some java code to do that